# How to target ng-show on specific items in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

http://plnkr.co/edit/aiGCPJEwTj0RWnuoCjsW?p=preview

I want the **remove button** to only show the popover for **that item**.

How would you go about this?
HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="acc in accounts">
    <div class="well well-sm">
        <div class="popover-remove" ng-show="popoverRemove">Click to remove item</div>
        <h4>{{acc.label}}</h4>
        <button class="btn btn-default"
                ng-mouseover="showPopover()"
                ng-mouseleave="hidePopover()">Remove</button>
    </div>
</li>
```

Angular Controller:

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('AccountsCtrl',
    ['$scope',
    function($scope) {

    var vs = $scope;

        vs.accounts = [
            {
                id: '1',
                label: 'Bitage'
            },
            {
                id: '2',
                label: 'Blockchain.info'
            },
            {
                id: '3',
                label: 'Coinbase wallet'
            },
            {
                id: '4',
                label: 'Xapo wallet'
            }
        ];

        vs.showPopover = function() {
            vs.popoverRemove = true;
        };

        vs.hidePopover = function() {
            vs.popoverRemove = false;
        };

    }]);
```

[image]

Comment: Try [$index](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Comment: [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/F1QFgL65kj5v6q1dMGpM?p=preview).

Comment: @AustinMullins awesome :) but one thing keep if you will gonna use filter on ng-repeat in that case $index will change and will not be applied (just for precaution).

Comment: Thanks @AustinMullins that is yet another neat way to solve this problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z20JTDgxzrZ2PsBkIKxp?p=preview) for you

The thing is that ng-repeat creates it's own scope.So, 'popoverRemove' is the local variable for each scope.You can set true or false to local variable by sending context to controller of that particular element of ng-repeat and set it's value using 'this'.

```
<button class="btn btn-default"
                    ng-mouseover="showPopover(this)"
                    ng-mouseleave="hidePopover(this)">Remove</button>

vs.showPopover = function(context) {
    context.popoverRemove = true;
};

vs.hidePopover = function(context) {
    context.popoverRemove = false;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Wow so many ways to accomplish this :) even found an Angular-ui popover https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: @LeonGaban yup :) Angular is amazing :)

Comment: So simple.. Works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a property on each iteration like so:

Instead of calling a function on the scope I simply set the value of `well.show` to true/false, but you get the jist of the idea!

```
    <li ng-repeat="acc in accounts track by $index">
      <div class="well well-sm">
        <div class="popover-remove" ng-show="well.show">Click to remove item</div>
        <h4>{{acc.label}}</h4>
        <button class="btn btn-default"
                ng-mouseover="well.show=true"
                ng-mouseleave="well.show=false">Remove</button>
      </div>
    </li>
```

[Plunker updated](http://plnkr.co/edit/TFENGWRPSTWyqZM16IyV?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Move popOverRemove to each accounts. Then you can control it from each child scope. Update your showPopover/hidePopover as well.

```
vs.accounts = [
    {
        id: '1',
        label: 'Bitage',
        popoverRemove: false
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        label: 'Blockchain.info',
         popoverRemove: false
    },
    {
        id: '3',
        label: 'Coinbase wallet',
       popoverRemove: false
    },
    {
        id: '4',
        label: 'Xapo wallet',
        popoverRemove: false
    }
];
```

I have updated here

http://plnkr.co/edit/uAjhiYTDyXIBmkxAQzzw?p=preview

Comment: it is a correct answer but do you really thing it is possible to add extra property to each object is a good choice ?.

Comment: Well, I have added popoverRemove in the json for your understanding. BUT basically when you used popoverRemove inside ng-repeat, angular automatically added in the childscope either it exists in json or not. You can check childscope object  in debugging tool for the verification. So it is almost identical to keep it in json or not